# Django deletes table data on its own

Tags: python, django, reactjs, postgresql, django-rest-framework

iam using Django rest framework , react.js for the frontend and postgresql...the problem which i think its weird django deletes product table data on its own after a while i dont know why ...iam using django since a year and i have never seen this before.

**this is my model**

```
class products(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Barcode=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category=models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description=models.TextField()
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=100)
    price=models.FloatField(default=100.0)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics',default='')
    cost=models.FloatField(default=100.0)
    branch=models.ForeignKey(branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Have any `category` or `branch` entries been deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if you have deleted category or branch record as this both field are `ForeignKey` and `on_delete=models.CASECADE`.

So if you delete any record in category or branch it related product record delete itself.

Comment: yup you are right its my fault which i recognized now while i am testing the app i have deleted some categories which deleted products for sure.. thank you

Comment: if you want to prevent automatic delete of child record. you can use 
on_delete=models.PROTECT 
This will not allow to delete your parent record until you delete its all child record.